# Youtube 360° Video - Very Bad Quality

Tags: video, youtube, youtube-data-api, 360-degrees

I am having huge trouble with YouTube. First off, I had to downscale my 7680x3840 video as YouTube 360 only supports mp4 of sizes up to 4096 on each axis, so I am running a video of 4096x2048.

On top of that, once I added the metadata and uploaded it to YouTube I got this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=l3PRqzevQ0U

A video so reduced in quality that I might as well not have uploaded anything and saved myself the effort.

Anyone know why YouTube is doing this, or what I may be doing wrong to turn a "looking fine before upload" video into something that looks like it was recorded with the worlds earliest digital camera?

Comment: probably it takes some time before all representations become available. Since youtube have to transcode the video to different qualities and it may take some time. Right now your video looks fine.

Comment: I don't think there is nearly enough info to help here. What are the technical details of the video, such as video/audio codecs? Did YT reduce the quality or did you put it through a conversion process? (I guess this is not a programming question so is off-topic, I expect _Super User_ is the site you need - however if you repost there please add much more detail).